# Ruby -- convert a nested hash to a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby, list, dictionary, hash

I have a hash which is named `h`. I want to store the contents in a multidimensional array named `ar`. I am getting the error `no implicit conversion from nil to integer`.

Here is my code:

```
h = {"bob" => {email: "abc" , tel: "123"} , "daisy" => {email: "cab" , tel: "123456"}}

keys = h.keys

l = h.length 

ar = Array.new(l) { Array.new(3) }

for i in 0..l-1
  ar[[2][i]] = keys[i]
  ar[[1][i]] = h[keys[i]][:email]
  ar[[0][i]] = h[keys[i]][:tel]
end

puts ar.to_s
```

The desired output is:

```
[[email_1, email_2, ..][tel_1, tel_2, ..][name_1, name_2, ..]]
```

For example:

```
[["abc", "cab"] , ["123", "123456"] , ["bob", "daisy"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I would handle this:

```
h.values.each_with_object({}) do |h,obj|
  obj.merge!(h) { |_k,v1,v2| ([v1] << v2).flatten }
end.values << h.keys
#=> [["abc", "cab"], ["123", "123456"], ["bob", "daisy"]]
```

- First grab all the `values` (as Hashes)
- loop through them with an accumulator (`{}`)
- `merge!` the values into the accumulator and on conflict append them to an `array`
- return the `values` from the accumulator
- then append the original `keys`

This is less explicit than @mudasobwa's answer and relies on the order of the first `value` to determine the output. e.g. if :tel came before :email the first 2 elements would have a reversed order

Comment: Your code works. Can you please  suggest a way to improve mine or tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: @AkshatBansal let's start with what you think `ar[[2][0]]` represents because it actually means `ar[2]` because you are creating an `Array` (`[2]`) and then calling `Array#[]` on it thus `[2][0] #=> 2` the problem here is that `[2][1] #=> nil`  so `ar[[2][1]]` is equivalent to `ar[nil]` which raises the error on the second iteration. what you meant was `ar[2][0]` and `ar[2][1]`  but that also has a mistake as `ar = [[nil,nil,nil],[nil,nil,nil]]` (notice no `ar[2]` only `ar[0]` and `ar[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

`[2][i]` returns `nil` for `i > 0`. `ar[nil]` raises the exception.

Here is what you do:

```
arr = h.map { |k, v| [v[:email], v[:tel], k] }.reduce(&:zip)
```

To make *your* code work:

Change

```
ar = Array.new(l) { Array.new(3) }
```

To

```
ar = Array.new(3) { Array.new(l) }
```

Change

```
ar[[2][i]] = keys[i]
ar[[1][i]] = h[keys[i]][:email]
ar[[0][i]] = h[keys[i]][:tel]
```

To

```
ar[2][i] = keys[i]
ar[1][i] = h[keys[i]][:email]
ar[0][i] = h[keys[i]][:tel]
```

Comment: Sorry i did not got your point , can you please tell what should i do to correct it

Comment: It is not giving error but also not giving the output needed.

Comment: +1 for explaining the problem with the OPs solution but please note your proposed solution only works with 2 keys in the main hash otherwise the output gains increasing depth

Answer (score 1):

What you mostly should do is to stop writing PHP code with Ruby syntax. Here it’s how is to be done in Ruby:

```
h.map { |k, v| [v[:email], v[:tel], k] }.reduce(&:zip)
```

or, even better, if you are certain of elements order in nested hashes:

```
h.map { |k, v| [*v.values, k] }.reduce(&:zip).map(&:flatten)
```

All the methods `map`, `reduce` and `zip` are thoroughly described in [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html).

Comment: Your *"even better"* relies on the need for the elements to be in the same order where as your first example (which is better) does not

Comment: @engineersmnky ...which is precisely described in the comment to “even better,” isn’t it?

Comment: describing a caveat does not make a solution "better" though does it? What makes it better? less key strokes?

Comment: @engineersmnky it does not depend on the amount of keys and their names. It’s extendable into both directions: one might add more keys to nested hashes, name them differently (and add more elements to the main hash.)

Comment: It does rely on the amount of keys being identical in each sub hash though otherwise values will be lost.  Additionally it only produces the correct result when `h` has 2 keys because of how `reduce(&:zip)` works

Comment: @engineersmnky indeed, I am always forgetting who does flatten the result and who does not. It would work for any amount of keys with `.map(&:flatten)` afterwards.

Comment: I hate to be a bother but both solutions need that same addition

Comment: @engineersmnky always welcome; The former one is likely the exact solution for the input given. The latter is the generalized. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
h.map { |k, v| [*v.values_at(:email, :tel), k] }.transpose
  #=> [["abc", "cab"], ["123", "123456"], ["bob", "daisy"]]
```

The intermediate calculation is as follows.

```
h.map { |k, v| [*v.values_at(:email, :tel), k] }
  #=> [["abc", "123", "bob"], ["cab", "123456", "daisy"]]
```